# Bars moving out x-axis

Tags: stacked-chart, echarts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMAG9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMAG9.png)Am using Echarts on this  project .Everything works fine but my stacked bar charts arent working as expected after a scale rendering which increases the x-axis scale .The bars move out of the x-axis as indicated on the screenshot.

here is my code down here

```
        $scope.$watch(attrs.eData, function (newValue, oldValue, scope) { 
            var legend = [],
              sData = [],
              data = newValue,
              chartName = '';
            series = newValue;

            var totalSubtitle = 0;
            angular.forEach(data, function (val) {
                legend.push(val.name);
            });
            option = {
                name: seriesName,
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    subtext: totalSubtitle,
                    x: 'center'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'item',
                    axisPointer: {
                        type: 'shadow'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'value',
                    min: 0,
                    axisTick: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    axisTick: {
                        alignWithLabel: false
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    scale: true,
                    data: [seriesName],
                    max: 100,
                    min: 100,
                    axisTick: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    orient: 'horizontal',
                    bottom: -29,
                    order: true,
                    data: legend
                },
                series: series
            };
            myChart.setOption(option);
        }, true);
        $scope.$watch(attrs.eOptions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            option.title.text = newValue.title.text;
            option.title.subtext = newValue.title.subtext;

            angular.forEach(newValue.series, function (val) {
                seriesName = val.name;
            });
            myChart.setOption(option);
        }, true);
        myChart.on('click', function (params) {
            $scope.SliceSelected(params);
        });
        $window.onresize = function () { 
            myChart.resize();
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some points from your code this may help you out in this issue.

`xAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    min: 0,
    axisTick: {
        show: true
    },
    axisTick: {
        alignWithLabel: false
    }
}`

**In the above mentioned code axisTick repeated two times**

And change the "xAxis" type to "category" and "yAxis" type to "value".

**Hope this will fix your issues**